# what happens to a substance when I bombard it with electrons?

Tags: electrons

What will happen to a gas when I bombard it with an electron beam? Will there be a reaction?

Comment: What gas? What are the specifications of the electron beam? Please clarify your question

Comment: You Ionize the gas; some particles of gas gain electrons. As a result the gas becomes charged. Electrons aren't great starters of chemical reactions. If i knock an electron out of an orbital, the atom will simply use the electron i used to knock the other one out instead. Photons are better for facilitating reactions because they themselves arent the subject of the reactions.

Comment: At the end you dissipate the electrons kinetic energy into EM radiation, depending from the electrons energy content into EM radiation from infrared up to X-Rays. Ionizated molecules get recombinated or in the case Chemical Vapour Deposition or sputtering some disturbed material condensates on other materials.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about electron ionization. Yes, there would be a "reaction"...the gas would be ionized. There would be a reaction of the form shown below, where $M$ is a molecule, $e^-$ is the electron, and $M^{+.}$ is the resulting molecular ion.

$M + e^- \rightarrow M^{+.} +2e^-$

Hope this helps!

More information about electron ionization can be found [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_ionization).

Comment: $\rightarrow$ is done by \rightarrow